# how to match such repeating pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I would like to match the pattern,789. using only one sed command.(no multiple commands linked with "-e")

The rule is to match the number after the third fax.

```
echo "fax 123 def fax tel 456 fax 789 fax 976" | sed 's/xxxxxxx/'
```

Comment: You know what your delimiters are, so you can do this without a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` with `fax` as the delimiter:

```
$ echo "fax 123 def fax tel 456 fax 789 fax ghi" | awk -F'fax ' '{print $4}'
789
```

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "fax 123 def fax tel 456 fax 789 fax ghi" | sed 's/.*fax \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
789
```

**Edit:** `sed` is line based so how about using `grep` to first split the fields:

```
$ echo "fax 123 def fax tel 456 fax 789 fax 976" | egrep -o 'fax (tel )?[0-9]+'
fax 123
fax tel 456
fax 789
fax 976
```

Then use `sed` to specify which line *(field)*:

```
 $ ... | sed -n '1s/^[^0-9]*//p'
 123

 $ ... | sed -n '2s/^[^0-9]*//p'
 456

 $ ... | sed -n '3s/^[^0-9]*//p'
 789
```

Comment: thanks, awk saves my life. I'm wondering if there's a way to resolve it with sed only. Match a repeating pattern?

Comment: I've added a `sed` solution, please accept this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I exactly want, ".*" makes it greedy. So it will match the number after the 4th fax. I have edited my question again. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I have my updated below. It's in sed only.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used a command like:

```
echo "  fax 123 def fax tel 456 fax 789 fax 012" |  
sed -e 's/^\s*fax\s*[0-9a-z]*\s*[a-z0-9]*\s*fax\s*[0-9a-z]*\s*[0-9a-z]*\s*fax\s*\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Trying using this to print 88th field `:|`

Comment: I know my command is ugly, but my condition is that I can use only one search command. It is actually to be used in the RegexExtract() in the Google spreadsheet XDDD

Comment: Now it make sense, that is the question you should have asked! You would have gotten much better answers.